# Is it legal to wear a short a little transparent like this, outside?

Tags: privacy, france, sexual-offences

Is it legal or prohibited to wear, for example in my garden where I can be seen by others, or at the beach, a semi-transparent shorts and my organs under (…like the picture)?

[image]

Comment: What location do you have in mind?  The answer will depend on that.

Comment: in France, in Europe

Answer (score 6):

Public nudity is not generally prohibited in most of Europe, only exhibitionism is (exhibitionism: openly presenting your private parts in a way to stimulate sexual desire).

Now that does not mean you can really walk around nude everywhere. If there are other people around, you may be fined for "public harassment". That will typically only give a small fine, though.

Particularly in Germany, but also in parts of France, beaches are normally fine. While there are often separate areas for nude bathing, usually people don't really care, unless there are a lots of children around. In Germany, almost nobody wears something for a swim before breakfast. And IIRC wearing nothing in your house or even in your garden is perfectly fine, even if it can be seen from outside.

So while you might be looked at strangely if you only wear those shorts (particularly in the middle of a town) I don't think much will happen.