# What is the legal status of publicly exposing one's breasts in England as a female?

Tags: england-and-wales, sexual-offences

Section 66 Sexual Offences Act 2003 addresses willful exposure of the genitals, as described by [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/85218/35069).

Is there anything wrong with exposing breasts in public for women in England and Wales?

Comment: @Lag Who's Bob? - - -

Comment: https://www.stuartmillersolicitors.co.uk/guide-indecent-exposure-laws-uk/

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-hampshire-33063397

Comment: https://www.letstalkbreasts.co.uk/general-breast-info/the-politics-of-breasts-know-your-rights